# Javascript closures. Why my "this" undefined in this method

Tags: javascript, closures

When I run this code I get a TypeError because `this.coverageList` is undefined. I suspect this has to do with a closure issue I can't see. The method `this.accumulateCoverage` is passed to the `forEach()` method of an `Array` instance.

```
igv.Coverage = function (genomicInterval) {

    this.accumulateCoverage = function (alignment) {

        var i, j, blocksBBoxLength;

        if (!this.coverageList) {

            this.coverageList = new Array(genomicInterval.end - genomicInterval.start);

            for (i = 0; i < this.coverageList.length; i++) {
                this.coverageList[ i ] = 0;
            }

        }

    };

    genomicInterval.features.forEach(this.accumulateCoverage);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) should take a context as the second argument:

```
genomicInterval.features.forEach(this.accumulateCoverage, this);
```

But this may depend on whether you're using a polyfill.  Support for `forEach` is relatively new, and may not be supported in all browsers.

The issue is that when you pass a function reference, it loses any association with the object it belongs to.  It's just a function.  It is only when you invoke the function using `object.method()` syntax that the function receives the implicit `this` argument (assigned to `object`).  That's why functions that take as input and execute another function usually allow you to provide the object that should be passed as `this` as well.

An alternative pattern that might suit your purpose is to assign `this` to a local variable outside of your function, so that it is included in the function closure.

```
igv.Coverage = function (genomicInterval) {
    var me = this;    
    function accumulateCoverage(alignment) {
        var i, j, blocksBBoxLength;

        if (!me.coverageList) {
           //...
        }
    };

    genomicInterval.features.forEach(accumulateCoverage);
}
```

This negates the need to pass around contexts like in the first solution.

Comment: Yep, using the local variable assignment - me = this - got "this" included in the closure which was what I was after. Thanks Mark. Cheers.